# Handler interrupt qaustion

Tags: android, timer, handler, thread-sleep

Today i get a open source for timer.
But this code has a little problem.

When I push the stop button over running this handler of app , it is well working to push start button.

But when I push start button and push pause button and push stop button, I have to start button twice.

I tried to fix this problem. But it was all just a big waste of time! T^T

The code is here.. plz help me

```
    public class StopWatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mStartBtn, mStopBtn, mRecordBtn, mPauseBtn;
    private TextView mTimeTextView, mRecordTextView;
    private Thread timeThread = null;
    private Boolean isRunning = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#4ea1d3"));
        }

        mStartBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        mStopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        mRecordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_record);
        mPauseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
        mTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeView);
        mRecordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recordView);

        mStartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mStopBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRecordBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                timeThread = new Thread(new timeThread());
                timeThread.start();
            }
        });

        mStopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mRecordBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mStartBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPauseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mRecordTextView.setText("");
                mTimeTextView.setText("00:00:00:00");
                timeThread.interrupt();


            }
        });

        mRecordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRecordTextView.setText(mRecordTextView.getText() + mTimeTextView.getText().toString() + "\n");
            }// 앞에 mRecordTextView.getText()은 n번이상 저장할때 첫번째 값을 n-1번째 라인에 놓고
        });  // n번째 저장한것을 n번째 놓기 위해서 설정

        mPauseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isRunning = !isRunning;
                if (isRunning) {
                    mPauseBtn.setText("PAUSE");
                } else {
                    mPauseBtn.setText("PAUSE");
                }
            }

        });
    }



    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int mSec = msg.arg1 % 100;
            int sec = (msg.arg1 / 100) % 60;
            int min = (msg.arg1 / 100) / 60;
            int hour = (msg.arg1 / 100) / 360;
            //1000이 1초 1000*60 은 1분 1000*60*10은 10분 1000*60*60은 한시간

            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            String result = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec, mSec);

            mTimeTextView.setText(result);
        }
    };

    public class timeThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;

            while (true) {
                while (isRunning) { //일시정지를 누르면 멈춤
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.arg1 = i++;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                mTimeTextView.setText("");
                                mTimeTextView.setText("00:00:00:00");
                            }
                        });
                        return; // 인터럽트 받을 경우 return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (isRunning) {` and its else do exactly the same thing. How will you know if it has actually toggled?

Comment: Thanks I got a hint from Andy Turner. The problem was isRunning. When I push the pause button isRunning turns to false. Therefore the timeThread class doesn' work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
mStartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mStopBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRecordBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            timeThread = new Thread(new timeThread());


            if(isRunning !=true){
                isRunning = true;     /This code is a solution that I think.
            }


            timeThread.start();
            Log.v("here is start ","stat!");
        }
    });
```

I got the solution. I upload the code to help for someone who have same promble like me